# Rails, Webpack & FontAwesome, how to stop conversion to SVG?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome

I've added FontAwesome pro with Yarn to my Rails 6 application and added it to application.js like this:

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/js/all";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css";
```

Before (when using FontAwesome through the asset pipeline) the generated HTML came out like this:

```
<i class="fal fa-heart-rate"></i>
```

Now it comes out like this:

```
<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-heart-rate fa-w-20" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fal" data-icon="heart-rate" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 640 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M480 224c-6.53 0-12.44 3.98-14.84 10.06l-45.62 114.05-84-335.98C333.72 4.86 327.69.17 319.62 0c-7.5.19-13.84 5.53-15.31 12.86l-82.06 410.23-46.72-186.97A16.005 16.005 0 0 0 160 224H8c-4.42 0-8 3.58-8 8v16c0 4.42 3.58 8 8 8h139.5l60.97 243.88c1.78 7.14 8.22 12.12 15.53 12.12h.38c7.5-.19 13.84-5.53 15.31-12.86l82.06-410.23 78.72 314.97c1.69 6.73 7.53 11.62 14.44 12.09 7.62.28 13.38-3.59 15.94-10.03l60-149.94H632c4.42 0 8-3.58 8-8v-16c0-4.42-3.58-8-8-8H480z"></path></svg>
```

Is there a way to prevent this?  I'm asking because I do stacking of icons which worked perfectly before and now it doesn't come out correctly anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the solution is pretty easy.

If you don't include the JS, this will not happen and everything will be rendered as before.

So in the application.js:

```
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/css/all.css";
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the JS and the font-icon appeared as li tag, like before, so you only need to remove the line:

> import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro/js/all";

Comment: That's indeed what I found out (see answer of May 14th)