# How to prevent webpack from transforming html icons to svg icons in fontawesome

Tags: css, webpack

Webpack automatically transfroms `<i class="fa fa-shopping-cart add-to-cart"></i>` to `<svg class="svg-inline--fa fa-cart-shopping add-to-cart" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" data-prefix="fas" data-icon="cart-shopping" role="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512" data-fa-i2svg=""><path fill="currentColor" d="M0 24C0 10.7 10.7 0 24 0H69.5c22 0 41.5 12.8 50.6 32h411c26.3 0 45.5 25 38.6 50.4l-41 152.3c-8.5 31.4-37 53.3-69.5 53.3H170.7l5.4 28.5c2.2 11.3 12.1 19.5 23.6 19.5H488c13.3 0 24 10.7 24 24s-10.7 24-24 24H199.7c-34.6 0-64.3-24.6-70.7-58.5L77.4 54.5c-.7-3.8-4-6.5-7.9-6.5H24C10.7 48 0 37.3 0 24zM128 464a48 48 0 1 1 96 0 48 48 0 1 1 -96 0zm336-48a48 48 0 1 1 0 96 48 48 0 1 1 0-96z"></path></svg>`

I wanted to style the html icon using CSS but since webpack automatically tranforms the element to svg, my styling is discarded

Comment: This seems to be the answer. Does it work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61794100/rails-webpack-fontawesome-how-to-stop-conversion-to-svg

Comment: This is how my imports look like:                                                                          
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/fontawesome";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/solid";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/regular";
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/brands";